How can I forbid '(click)' on my component in Angular?
I have a custom button component with an (action) emitter that is triggered by multiple events (click and keyDown). I'd like the users of my button to use (action) but I know they will use (click) because it's so natural.
What I'd like ideally is to trigger a compilation error saying that using (click) on this component is forbidden. This is probably not possible, so an acceptable alternative would be to throw an Error when the component is initialized, or when the outer (click) method is fired.
I have no clue on how I can do that, any idea ?
I'm on Angular 17.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ ButtonModule ],
  template: '<p-button (click)="emit()" (keydown.enter)="emit()" />'
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() public action = new EventEmitter();

  public emit(): void {
    this.action.emit();
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    // Here: if someone writes <app-button (click)="someFunc()" />,
    // I want to throw an error and say that they need to use "(action)" instead
  }
}

What I want my team to write:
<app-button (action)="doSomething()" />

But intuitively, we will write:
<app-button (click)="doSomething()" />

I just want to make our life easier in the long run and find a way to fail if we use the wrong one.
Users should of course be able to click on the button, but the click should be catched by the internal <p-button />

would you like to add :host {display: inline-block;} instead? so (click) handler would work perfectly fine as well

pointer-events: none

are you trying to prevent the user from clicking or another engineer from changing your code?  ...or XSS attack?

@browsermator I want to make my button accessible, specifically I want (click) to always have a matching (keydown) to be used by keyboard only. So I'm encapsulating a button with this custom one and want people to use (action) on it. But they still can add (click) and defeat my strategy; so I want to find a way to prevent them adding (click).  The user should of course be able to click on the button, but going through my (action).

This is a process/training issue.

you might call it "app-button-dont-use-(click)-use-(action)".  (I'm only half-kidding)  I'm not sure any of this is necessary though... the enter key while tabbed to this button should fire click methinks...

Just add a (click) @Output to your component that points to your (action). Then consumers can write (click) and you'll get (action). They're happy; you're happy.

@mxmissile: yes but I like having a minimum of those.
@browsermator: it fires with (onClick), not sure with (click) in this exact configuration.
@HereticMonkey: tried it and while this works, there is still Sonar to make happy (it sees a (click) without a (keyDown)).

What you're asking for is not a production answer but a development answer. If your project has some sort of continuous integration, you may want to write a custom lint rule that checks the codebase for uses of (click).
There's a simple example for Angular rules that I haven't created but your lint rule would similarly look for click handlers and throw an error if they are found.
When that error is thrown, it sends a notice to the developer for correction and can prevent code submission upstream.

You are right it is a development answer, and we have Sonar that's finding those mistakes right now. The feedback loop is just very slow and I'm all for preventing those mistakes the earliest possible.
Your suggestion to use ESLint is interesting, I wonder why I didn't think about it... We do have it set up in the project, IDEs and the linter runs in the CI.

Found this rule. This is probably the best thing to use as it covers this accessibility problem more widely.

If that rule doesn't work for you it seems like it'd be easy to fork and modify.

So after some struggling and using hints from the kind comments I got, I managed to log an error in the console when it is used with a (click).
Here is a minimal working example:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ ButtonModule ],
  template: `
    <p-button (click)="emit()" (keydown.enter)="emit()" [label]="label()">
      <ng-content/>
    </p-button>
  `
})
export class ButtonComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  /** Don't use (click), use (action) */
  @Output() public click = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() public action = new EventEmitter();
  
  public label = input<string>();

  readonly #elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement> = inject(ElementRef);

  public emit(): void {
    this.action.emit();
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if(this.click.observed) {
      const label = this.label() ?? this.#elementRef.nativeElement.innerText;
      console.error(`<app-button> '${label}' is using (click), use (action) instead`);
    }
  }
}

As you can see the solution was to have a click emitter, and check its observed property.
It works in the ngOnInit() method, I used ngAfterViewInit() so I can get the <ng-content /> text.
The result is a nice error in the console.
Also the doc comment on the click emitter is displayed when typing:


Yes but this is only on the comment level, they can still use (click).
The proper way for this is to extend p-button component and override click

@tony

Yes of course they can still use (click). My goal is to prevent mistakes. They are not trying to brute force using the (click), it's just too natural so I'm pushing visible & early hints that they will happily follow.
Also, (click) cannot ne overridden by extending p-button, as it belongs to the core framework, you can set it on any element.

